# Create Bucket Ceph with Spring

Tags: java, ceph

I am not sure how to create a bucket `Ceph` with Spring.

Are there any documents I can prefer? 
How to get this accessKey and secretKey?

```
String accessKey = "insert your access key here!";
String secretKey = "insert your secret key here!";

AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
conn.setEndpoint("objects.dreamhost.com");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow Ceph's official documentation. 
Docs: https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/s3/java/

To get `accessKey` and `secretKey` please follow this step. 
https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/s3/authentication/. 
https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/keystone/

`openstack --os-interface public ec2 credentials create`